# Adding hosted Feature Layer from AGOL to my local ArcGIS Pro through Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api

I`m trying to find a way to add an online layer to my local map, through Python. I know how to grab the layer info, but don't know how to use it.

```
onlinelayer = gis.content.search(mylayer)[0]
itemid= onlinelayer.id
```

I got the item ID  but how do I apply it using something similar to addDataFromPath()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
aprx = arcpy.mpArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
itemid = '2ec9f27bea254a428e4eb70e7650672d'
m.addDataFromPath("https://mycounty.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=" + itemid)
```

The layer gets added to the Pro map.