# Use Existing AGOL Hosted Feature Layer in Standalone Python Script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, python-3.7

I have written a Python (Python 3 for ArcGIS Pro) script to update a layer using values from a CSV table.  The script works fine and I have a workflow that will allow me to overwrite a hosted feature layer with the updated values.

This is great, but I'm trying to update another feature layer that has been published by another user, without having to republish or overwrite the other user's feature layer.

Is there a way to bring the hosted feature layer into my script?

I cannot figure out how to reference the AGOL item in my script.   I'd like to be able to join tables and run other gp tools on it, without having to republish the layer.

The part where the layer gets republished looks like this, but I want to be able to just call the layer without having to republish it each time:

```py
try:
    print("Updating AGOL web layer....")
    arcpy.SignInToPortal("https://myportal.maps.arcgis.com", "Username", "Password")   
    outdir = r"S:\Data\Fires\Fire_Mapping_Analysis"
    service_name = "Brush Fire Perimeters"
    sddraft_filename = service_name + ".sddraft"
    sddraft_output_filename = os.path.join(outdir, sddraft_filename)
    sd_filename = service_name + ".sd"
    sd_output_filename = os.path.join(outdir, sd_filename)
    aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"S:\Data\Fires\Fire_Mapping_Analysis\Fire_Mapping_Analysis.aprx")
    m = aprx.listMaps ('Map')[0]
    selected_layer = m.listLayers()[0]
    server_type = "HOSTING_SERVER"
    sddraft = m.getWebLayerSharingDraft(server_type, "FEATURE", service_name, selected_layer)
    sddraft.overwriteExistingService = True
    sddraft.description = "Brush fire web layer used in the Brush Fire Report Web Map Application"
    sddraft.summary = "Brush fire web layer used in the Brush Fire Report Web Mapping Application"
    sddraft.tags = "FireDept, Brush Fire"
    sddraft.useLimitations = "The data herein is for informational purposes, and may not have been prepared for or be suitable for legal, engineering, or surveying intents."
    sddraft.exportToSDDraft(sddraft_output_filename)
    arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft_output_filename, sd_output_filename)
    print ("Uploading new service definition...")
    arcpy.server.UploadServiceDefinition(sd_output_filename, server_type, '', '', "FROM_SERVICE_DEFINITION", '', "STARTED", "OVERRIDE_DEFINITION", "SHARE_ONLINE", "PUBLIC", "SHARE_ORGANIZATION", None)
```

Comment: Hi there! It might help if you show us what your script looks like (or at least the part that you use to read in **your** hosted feature layer).

Comment: Oh yes of course....I just added that piece in my post.  I just want to be able to use the layer as a variable so I can run tools on it after publishing it and not overwrite it each time...of that is at all possible.

Comment: So are you just wanting bring a hosted layer you have no authority over, perform work and then push your own work to AGO? I am just a little confused by your description of your workflow.  You can call in layers from AGO in a script by using the Map class' method: `Map.addDataFromPath()`; it simply takes a URL of item's details on AGO. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337805/how-to-add-a-hosted-feature-layer-from-agol-to-my-local-arcgis-pro-through-pytho

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try adding from path and see if that will do it.  It's a collaborative project within my org, but I'm trying to automate some of the updates so we don't have to manually go in and update the layer's table.  We have these reports that get generated as csv files, they we've been having to join this with the layer's table, calculate the fields, then save edits in the AGOL layer.  I could also change ownership of the data I suppose, but thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

I perform similar workflow daily. I use a hybrid of arcpy and the AGOL Python API.

```
import arcpy
from arcgis import GIS

## connect to AGOL (home will work if you are logged into ArcGIS Pro with AGOL username)
conn = GIS("home")
## otherwise use credentials
#conn = GIS("org agol url", "username", "password")

## The feature service id - replace with the fs id that contains the layer you
## want to perform updates/edits on
fs_id = "9659d22a788e48d98877f467057ead80"

## access the item via the fs_id
item = conn.content.get(fs_id)

## get the url for the layer in the feature service based on the layer name
## replace layer_name with your layer name, NOTE: note the feature service name
## the layer name within the feature service, there can be one or multiple
lyr = [lyr.url for lyr in item.layers if lyr.properties.name == 'layer_name'][0]
print(lyr)

## you can now use this lyr in most arcpy tools for geoprocessing
## for example, I export to excel, or add attachments.
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(lyr, "excel_export.xls", "ALIAS", "DESCRIPTION")
```

You can also use the Search, Update, and Insert cursors but I recommend getting familiar with the AGOL Python API for editing (especially if editing attributes). Here's a snippet for updating one feature based on a unique identifier

```
## access the layer
lyr = [lyr for lyr in item.layers if lyr.properties.name == 'layer_name'][0]

## sql type query
query_string = "fld_name = 'something_unique'"
## use the query to limit the results returned in the lyr using unique identifier
query = lyr.query(where=query_string)
## query returns a list so looking at the one specific feature to update
update_feature = [f for f in query.features][0]
edit = update_feature
## upodate the attribute
edit.attributes['update_field'] = 3
lyr.edit_features(updates=[edit])
```